# Application rollup and tree shaking

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

What we got here is a pretty big `Angular 2` application which was mostly developed as angular was still young and there was no working `compiler-cli` and stuff like that. As that was done I always got idea in mind that at some point we'll have a tree shaking and AoT compilation and I'm trying to make it work with some interval and still haven't managed.

The problem is that whenever I try to apply any of `rollup` routines that can be found in plenty over the www I stumble upon something ... else each time.

I assume that what makes this build different from others that can be seen on web is the project layout - we're having here a bunch of self written external `Angular 2` npm modules that encapsulate some generic functionality to final project and those should be included in final bundle.

So the layout is:

1) There are multiple `npm` modules that contain `TypeScript` source files accompanied with `JavaScript` versions transpiled to `es2015` format;

2) There is an application that has its own modules that rely heavy on those imported from external `npm` modules;

3) And I don't ask for much - I just want to: a) pack em all within tree shaked bundle and as that is done; b) implement AoT compilation for production builds with very same layout;

## The problem

Whenever I try to use most simple `rollup` module example I eventually stumble into something like: `'createPlatformFactory' is not exported by node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js (imported by node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\src\platform-browser-dynamic.js). For help fixing this error see https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module` and this happen when I try to transpile project to `JavaScript` and then bundle it with `rollup` or even when I try to launch it all via `rollup-plugin-typescript`.

My assumption on this one is that, even though Angular sources since RC6 are in `es2015` format `core.umd.js` is not - it's in `UMD` format which has different imports/exports etc.

So, can anyone confirm that this is a problem? Also, how to we solve this? (I really have tried all problem solving strategies I could imagine and none of them worked.)

Hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as mentioned above, is within fact that `rollup` targets umd output bundles instead of es6 source files and that can be solved, as I've found out, by redirecting angular module request paths to source files, like this:

`` if (id.startsWith('@angular/')) {
   return `${__dirname}/node_modules/${id}/index.js`;
} ``

And, as that is done `rollup` procedure goes on without errors. That surely sounds like a success, but it's not ...

In result I don't see any notices on dropped methods, as I would expect, and I don't see any significant decrease in output bundle size.

Also, as output bundle is attempted to be converted to es5 format by running something like:

`tsc --target es5 --allowJs ./dist/bundle.es2015.js --out ./dist/bundle.js`

I get an error of `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` from `node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:37826`

So it's same again - one problem solved leads to another and still no result.

Any ideas on how to deal with this would be much appreciated!

And by the way - anyone has got any idea how would @angular tree shaking work in any of examples that can be found on internet, taking into account that all of them obviously targeted UMD bundles and not ES6 source files?